# Do I get charged to purchase my own app in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play

As a Google Play Store publisher, do I get charged to purchase my own app assuming I am using the same Google ID as the administrator of the Google Play Store entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting with tech support @ Google.  It appears it is not possible and developers/test must either side-load or pay for the app in order to test it from the Play Store.

Google has no support for "app promo codes" like Apple App Store and up until now does not have the support for making an app *free temporarily*.